# How to check if NSTimer auto-invalidation has been made?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have a problem when creating an NSTimer without repeat.

Imagine I create a new instance

`timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateSystems) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`

somewhere in my code.

If I press the home button on the Iphone, my app will enter background state, and the timer will still be around, just be paused. So in my `applicationDidEnterBackground` method I say

```
if(timer.isValid == YES)
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

The problem arises if I press the Home button after the timer has completed. Then the timer has been released, resulting in a crash when trying to access isValid.

Trying

```
if(timer != nil) 
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

results in the same crash, since Cocoa's auto-invalidation doesn't seem to set the timer to `nil`.

How is it possible to check wether the timer has auto-invalidated or not?

Thank you.

NOTE: The reason I need to do this is because I'm sending a request to a web service, once the request has been successful (or a failure) I start a timer that will send a new request once it gets fired. If I don't invalidate the timer before it's finished, several timers will be created (since I'm making a new request on `applicationDidBecomeActive`) making multiple request when only one is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retain the timer yourself to guarantee that it's still around after it has fired. `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` returns an autoreleased instance that you don't own.

Comment: I don't want it to still be around, I just want to check if it's still around.

Comment: There is no easy way to find out if the pointer still holds a valid objective-c object. retaining the timer it the correct way to do it. You should always retain objects you want to access later to prevent crashes when something else that retains the object releases it.

Comment: So I should retain the timer and then check wether the retain count is greater than 1, if so I know the auto-invalidate has not been accessed. Still there could be some timing issues, since the timer is running in a different thread. When I check the retain count condition and it says greater than 1, there will still be a possibility that auto-invalidation will run before I do things based on my condition?

Comment: No. You should release the timer and set it to nil after it has fired.

Comment: So I could retain it until I create a new timer, but the same thing could happen then: If I press the home button in between the release and the new creation of a new timer, no timer will exist, yet again resulting in a crash when entering applicationDidEnterBackground.

Comment: That's why you'd set your timer to nil after releasing it.

Comment: You just saved my Day with that answer omz. thx
And thx to Man of One Way for asking. :)

Comment: You MUST use retain on a timer is you are going check if it has been invalidate (or are going to us it in a IF statement). Here is related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399669/iphone-crash-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance